# How do I detect that all frames have returned responses from a contentscript in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want my Chrome extension to rerun a contentscript for all open tabs prior to viewing the popup window to gather the most recent data about each webpage (it sends a message to the background page).  My problem is that in order to get full access to each iframe, I need to set allframes to true.  This means that prior to showing the popup window, I need to wait until I have received a message from each frame.

My problem is that I am not sure how to determine how many frames there are.  One approach I looked at would be to detect the frame count from within the contentscript, but there is an open bug which indicates that you can't request that right now.  Another is to just wait for a number of responses equivalent to what I got when I first navigated to the page, but it is possible that due to AJAX calls the number of frames increased since then.  Finally, I was hoping that the response to chrome.extension.SendRequest would include such information but it does not.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you always run the content script from the manifest, so that the content script will run every time a new frame loads. Then, have the content script open a port to the extension, so that every open frame has a port to the background. Then it's up to the background page to keep track of all the open ports for each tab, and send messages to the desired ports.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I'll look into using ports to improve communication between contentscripts and the background page.  However, I still have the problem that the contentscript doesn't always get run for new frames (it works okay at http://www.reddit.com/r/videos but doesn't seem to work for Facebook videos.)

Comment: Actually, it looks like the problem is with any video embedded on Facebook (and not specific to Facebook Video).  When I get a chance I'll view source and compare how iframes are embedded on each site (and possibly file a bug if expected behavior is that contentscript should be run on new iframes as they are created.)

Comment: I had tested a content script that simply did console.log('injected!'), and whenever I used the developer console to append an iframe and navigate, the content script would run. I hope you figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  If you (or anyone) want to reproduce the problem, go to Facebook (assuming you have an account) and find some video included in the news feed or on a wall.  When you click Play it will create a new iframe but it doesn't run the content script for that frame unless you have something (such as a popup) explicitly send a message to all frames.

Comment: At least for the videos on my wall, they all are Flash applications and don't generate new iframes. The script can find the embed element, but there's no new frame for the video.

Comment: It looks like you answered my question. Thanks.  I'm guessing that when you load a video on a Facebook newsfeed/wall, it updates the DOM to include the video within an existing frame.  So I still need to requery the page if I want to become aware of the new element, but I can find out through an existing frame instead of expecting a new one to be discovered.